# MYSQL SELECT from Two Tables, substract expenses from earnings = total earnings

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables which I want to query in MySQL.  As follows:

```
**Table: Monthly Expenses**
Purchase Date  | Cost Price
----------------------------
05-25-21       | 100
06-26-21       | 200
07-27-21       | 550
```

I need a query which selects each monthly expenses to be added to my second table (Monthly Earnings) and adding it up to total earnings (earnings - expenses = total earnings)

So for example, the output would look like this

```
Output:
**Table: Monthly Earnings**
Monthly Date  | Earnings  | Expenses   | Total Earnings |   
--------------------------------------------------------
05-25-21      |  1000     |     100    |      900
06-25-21      |  2000     |     200    |     1800
07-25-21      |  3000     |     550    |     2450
```

So far I have tried the following query but it doesn't add up or show up

```
  String sql =   "SELECT   SUM(`Earnings`) AS Earnings, `Monthly_Date`  FROM  pet_transaction    GROUP BY month(Payment_Date)";  
  &&  SUM(`Cost_Price`) AS Cost_Price, `Purchase Date` FROM  clinic_expenses GROUP BY month(Purchase Date)";
```

Comment: Please leave out all the irrelevant tags to this question (only `mysql` is good enough).

Comment: Can you share the DDL for table `Monthly Expenses` and the table `Monthly Earnings` ?

Comment: DDL for table Monthly Expenses:  "SELECT   SUM(`Cost_Price`) AS Cost_Price, `Purchase Date` FROM  clinic_expenses GROUP BY month(Purchase Date)";  and DDL for Monthly Earnings : "SELECT   SUM(`Earnings`) AS Earnings, `Monthly_Date`,  FROM  transaction GROUP BY month(Monthly_Date)";

Comment: I wanna show in the table "Monthly Earnings" is to put expenses which comes from another table "Monthly Expenses" then you subtract the earnings from expenses = total earnings

Comment: your queries don't run with full GROUP By and you still need a joining inofrmation as month/Year . Also test your queries against a table with multiple years of data

Answer (score 0):

You need for such purposes a FULL JOIN which MySQL doesn't have

This Query will give you what you search.

It looks a bit different, but you can format the date as you like

```
SELECT e_month,e_year,COALESCE(Earnings,0),COALESCE(Cost_Price,0), COALESCE(Earnings,0) - COALESCE(Cost_Price,0) total
FROM
(SELECT   SUM(`Earnings`) AS Earnings, MONTH(Payment_Date) e_month,YEAR(Payment_Date) e_year   FROM  pet_transaction    GROUP BY MONTH(Payment_Date),YEAR(Payment_Date)) e LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT  SUM(`Cost_Price`) AS Cost_Price, MONTH(Purchase_Date) c_month,Year(Purchase_Date) c_year FROM  clinic_expenses GROUP BY MONTH(Purchase_Date),Year(Purchase_Date)) c  ON e.e_month = c.c_month AND e.e_year = c.c_year
UNION 
SELECT c_month,c_year,COALESCE(Earnings,0),COALESCE(Cost_Price,0), COALESCE(Earnings,0) - COALESCE(Cost_Price,0) total
FROM
(SELECT   SUM(`Earnings`) AS Earnings, MONTH(Payment_Date) e_month,YEAR(Payment_Date) e_year   FROM  pet_transaction    GROUP BY MONTH(Payment_Date),YEAR(Payment_Date)) e RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT  SUM(`Cost_Price`) AS Cost_Price, MONTH(Purchase_Date) c_month,Year(Purchase_Date) c_year FROM  clinic_expenses GROUP BY MONTH(Purchase_Date),Year(Purchase_Date)) c  ON e.e_month = c.c_month AND e.e_year = c.c_year
```